# extract data from sql, modify it and save the result to a table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

This may seem like a dumb question. I am wanting to set up an SQL db with records containing numbers. I would like to run an enquiry to select a group of records, then take the values in that group, do some basic arithmetic on the numbers and then save the results to a different table but still have them linked with a foreign key to the original record. Is that possible to do in SQL without taking the data to another application and then importing it back? If so, what is the basic function/procedure to complete this action?

I'm coming from an excel/macro/basic python background and want to investigate if it's worth the switch to SQL.

PS. I'm wanting to stay open source.

Comment: Sounds like a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` could do that. But without more details, that's not certain.

Comment: So which one is this???  MySQL <> Postgres!!!

Comment: I am currently looking at both mysql and Postgres. I expect that if there is a solution in one, then there will be a solution in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tiny example using postgresql (9.6)

```
-- Create tables
CREATE TABLE initialValues(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  value int
);

CREATE TABLE addOne(
   id serial,
   id_init_val int REFERENCES initialValues(id),
   value int
);

-- Init values
INSERT INTO initialValues(value)
SELECT a.n
FROM generate_series(1, 100) as a(n);

-- Insert values in the second table by selecting the ones from the 
-- First one .
WITH init_val as (SELECT i.id,i.value FROM initialValues i)
INSERT INTO addOne(id_init_val,value)
(SELECT id,value+1 FROM init_val);
```

Comment: Thanks. You are a wiz!

Comment: Is it possible to take the value from InitialValues where id= 5 and the value from InitialValues where id=10, add them together and store them into Addon where id=20? Or is that asking too much?

Comment: 'insert into addOne(id,id_init_val,value)
select 20,5, sum(value) from initialValues
where id in (10,5) 
on conflict(id) do nothing;'

Comment: Thanks again. I am content that I can move forward with my project in postgresql. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use CREATE TABLE ... SELECT (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html)